# Why do Sorghum Bicolor leaves roll up?

Tags: botany, homework, plant-physiology, endocrinology

In A level Bio today we talked about abcesic acid as a stress hormone, and its ability to reduce osmotic potential around guard cells to close stomata.

My question is, is abscesic acid in sorghum bicolor leaves responsible for its ability to roll up in lack of water?